# Latest Android 10 Bug - aframe AR doesn't work on mobile

Tags: android, mobile, augmented-reality, aframe

My aframe AR example works perfect on desktop (webcam), but on mobile CHROME it does nothing.

Marker: HIRO 
Demo-Link: https://laft.digital/ar

Before the android update it works perfect on any mobile device ...

Did somebody have the same problem?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: SOLVED. It was a Corse policy thing, which doesn't appear before.

Comment: Add an answer with an explanation of what you did. It could be helpful to other people in the future!